# Does the time of day affect stealth in Red Dead Redemption II on the PC?

Tags: red-dead-redemption-2

In Red Dead Redemption II on the PC, does the time of day affect stealth mechanics?

For example, if I'm tasked with stealing something - such as the Cornwall Oil Wagon - will it be easier to sneak past the guards if I attempt the mission at night?